# How to get response back from Django API to Calling HTML Page i am posting an image to Api?

Tags: django, api

How I can call a Django API from another Django Project (or from any other project) and get the response back after some processing on the same calling page (the page from which I called the API)

I am calling the API from form action ....but API shows the response in a new blank page

Here is API CODE: (//skipping some code to avoid confusion)

```
def IdealWeight(request):
 
#defining a list of data to send back to html
list_of_data=[]
list_of_data.append(name)
list_of_data.append(fatherName)
list_of_data.append(registration)

print(list_of_data)

# outPut_Data = ast.literal_eval(list_of_data)

    # return render(request,'LibraryForm.html',{'data1':outPut_Data})


 return JsonResponse(list_of_data,safe=False)
```

I want list_of_data on the calling page in some variable.

Here is my HTML Code from which i am calling the API:

```
 <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/idealweight/?image/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}

    
          <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);"  required>
       
          <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary" title="Process" value="Process" id="processButton">
        </div> 

     

      {{ data1 }}
      
         </form>
```

> From HTML page, I am sending a picture to API (API build in Django)
> and from that, I want to send an array or list of data extracted from the image and want to show that on same HTML page....................from which I called the API how I can do that?
> hope I am clear what I want?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is xhr/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using an Ajax call would be better choice. you would be doing something along the line.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#upload').on('click', function () {
        var file_data = $('#file').prop('file');
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/idealweight/?image/',
          contentType: false,
          data: form_data,
          type: 'post',
          success: function (response) {
                       // use response to update html
                   },
          error: function (response) {
                       // use response to update html
                  }
          });
     });
});
```

and your template would be something like

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<button id="upload" type="button">Process</button>
```

note: you might get **cross origin request block** error. so you have to allow that explicitly.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: where i have wrote this code? in my form?i am new please be kind.....

Comment: @ASIF inside your script block in html. I suggest you read or follow a tutorial about Ajax first.

Comment: Thanks, i am doing...once i did i will conform here....

Comment: update your question with what you have tried so far. and your api view method. your ```IdealWeight``` doesn't seems to be handling any file upload.

Comment: THE above technique did not worked for me as i can't upload the image when i enable the e.preventDefault();

Comment: @ASIF I have updated the answer with a bit more details. however do not expect it to work as is.I can't write your code for you, I can only give you hints.

Comment: sir can you share your email?

Comment: sorry, i can't. follow this https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/  this should be helpful.

Comment: can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756044/how-i-can-pass-image-as-argument-in-python-request-along-with-url-as-2nd-argumen